# Change 343 into 42 in a short chunk of Java code

Tags: java, loops

I am aware, that this type of question might be considered as not fitting in the scope of StackOverflow. If it gets down-voted I will remove it, but I really find it interesting.

I found the following, intriguing, interview task, for which I still don't see any smart/tricky solution and I wonder what would people come up with.

> Extend the following chunk of code with minimal number of lines in such a way that its answer will always be `42`. You are not allowed to use assignments (including incrementation) and to modify existing lines of code.

```
public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iters = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
                    iters++;
                }
            } 
        }
        System.out.println(iters);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

One suggested answer is

```
System.out.println(42);
System.exit(0);
```

and it is correct.

However, the program should end up naturally (without terminating it manually), and, I guess, the value of `iters` should not be checked directly we should test the indexes: `i,j,k`.

My idea was to add 6 lines:

```
public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iters = 0;
        loopA: //added
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            loopB: //added
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
                    iters++;
                }
                if (j == 2) //added
                    break loopB; //added
            } 
            if (i == 1)  //added
                break loopA;  //added
        }
        System.out.println(iters);
    }
}
```

Comment: *System.out.println(42);* ?

Comment: `System.out.println("Oh, sorry, I meant " + 42);` :-)

Comment: Well... fair enough. I added info - existing code should not be modified and `-=` is an assignment

Comment: `System.out.println(42); System.exit(0);`

Comment: Add a if condition in outer for loop to break if iters==42

Comment: I can see doing it for 49...

Comment: This is a very poorly conceived interview question...

Comment: @kailoon Yeah, with just one additional line.

Comment: @mypetlion Absolutely. I wonder what exactly were the interviewers intending to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one `if` clause before incrementing `iters`

```
int iters = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
            if (i > 0 && i == j) // Added 1 line
            iters++;
        }
    } 
}
System.out.println(iters);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip some specific iterations, because of 42:

```
public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iters = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (j < 6)
                    for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
                        if (k == 0)
                            iters++;
                    }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(iters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is "cheating" or "showing off the hacks that you learned while dissecting legacy codebases", but I'll add it here:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Question
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out)
        {
            @Override
            public void println(int x)
            {
                System.err.println(42);
            }
        });

        int iters = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
                {
                    iters++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(iters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will do and does not need any super logical reasoning

### **[Demo](https://ideone.com/Ry0rvn)**

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int iters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (j == 6) break;     // <----------------------
            for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
                iters++;
            }
        }
        break; // <------------------------------------------
    }
    System.out.println(iters);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way I could see doing it was to break early and not do one loop.

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/Wx6YbO)

```
public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iters = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (j == 6) continue;
                for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
                    iters++;
                }
            }    
            break;         
        }
        System.out.println(iters);
    }
}
```

Comment: `iters--` is an assignment.

Comment: How about `if (iters == 42) break;` instead?

Comment: Hmm, I guess technically decrement does perform an assignment. I thought maybe he strictly meant using the "=" operation in some shape or form.